# Free push logs tool for GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a GitLab instance on my server and  I'm going to create users for my students to do their assignments there. I was wondering whether there is a free push log tool for GitLab which can show these items:

```
-who initiated the push
-which protocol was used
-what the originating IP address was
-which Git client was used
-and any other useful information to checkout commit requests
```

It is because I want to catch some cases of plagiarism.

Comment: You can look if such details appear in the audit log (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/audit_events.html), but there is nothing which would stop a malicious user to change the commit details before a push.

Answer (score 1):

There is this [gitlab-auditor](https://github.com/kfei/gitlab-auditor) on github.

It basically parses the [`gitlab-shell-log`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/logs.html#gitlab-shell-log) and present the information in an organized way.

*Don't forget to apply the patches indicated in the `README` because they enable some important info to those logs.*